# JavaScript TypeError, prints object as '#<Object>' string

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, tostring

Probably a naive question - if this snippet is executed (I'm running with Node.js `v12.16.3`, same result in Chrome apart from the error type):

```js
const obj = {}

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'a', {
  writable: false,
  value: 13
})

obj.a = 14
```

It will, obviously, throw an error, but the message string of that error has strange representation of an object:

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'a' of object '#<Object>'

The question is - why it's stringified as `#<Object>`?

Defining a `toString` method on the object will render it as if it were called with `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)`:

```js
const obj = {
  toString () {
    return 'stringified obj'
  }
}

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'a', {
  writable: false,
  value: 13
})

console.log(`${obj}`)

obj.a = 14
```

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'a' of object '[object Object]'

While `console.log` outputs correctly. How to make that `TypeError` output the correct string representation? What does it use internally?

Comment: interestingly this happens only with `"use strict";`. Youre using babel in your snippet. Babel uses strict-mode. Without strict mode no error will be shown. Maybe it has something to do with the strict mode and the error - handling of it.

Comment: Correct, this error is explicitly thrown only in strict mode, but I have no evidence that the strict mode represents objects differently. Probably it's just an internal switch to throw or silently do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js and Chrome share the same JavaScript engine called [V8](https://v8.dev). That engine hard-codes the string "#" in the error message.

It uses [the template](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:v8/src/common/message-template.h;l=298-299):

```
T(StrictReadOnlyProperty,                                                    \
    "Cannot assign to read only property '%' of % '%'")
```

Which in turn gets interpolated as the [object's constructor name](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:v8/src/objects/objects.cc;l=2757;bpv=1;bpt=1). In this case `Object`. You can see this:

```js
const obj = {};
obj.constructor.name; // Object

const obj2 = new class Bar {};
obj2.constructor.name; // Bar
```

Or, in your example:

```js
const obj = new class SomeValue {}

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'a', {
  writable: false,
  value: 13
})

// TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'a' of object '#<SomeValue>'
obj.a = 14
```

Note the spec just says: "throw a TypeError exception." - this behaviour is entirely defined by the V8 engine and not JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It is interesting though that defining `toString` on the object  changes the object representation in the error message to `[object Object]`.

Comment: @DamagedOrganic it is, and enough so that a special symbol [Symbol.toStringTag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag) is defined to control this behaviour and the behaviour of what happens when you call `Object.prototype.toString.call(myObject)`. I am not sure why V8 chose to use the constructor name here - Thanks for the interesting question.

Comment: Apparently, at the moment there's no way to control this behavior from Node.js runtime directly, so the answer above is exhaustive. Thank you.

Comment: @DamagedOrganic I am a maintainer of said Node.js runtime - if there is a legitimate need to customize this please open an issue! (or email me (my email is in the Node.js repo home page at GitHub) and I will if you'd rather not).

Comment: Also - happy to help with the actual question - always fun to dig in V8 and figure why they do stuff ^^